# Song Quality and sound through speakers

Tags: mixing, rap

I’m a new Hip Hop artist in Atlanta and my songs are sounding really good on my headphones and ear buds but speakers not so much, any tips?

Comment: Could be the mix, could be the speakers, could be the room, could be your expectations. We'll need more information to give a meaningful answer. Which headphones, which speakers, not so good in what way?

Answer (score 3):

This is the 'holy grail' of the beginner sound engineer - how to make a mix that's portable.

The only way to really do it is **practise**.

Headsets of any kind are notoriously forgiving compared to speakers, so concentrate on getting it right on many sets of speakers.

Mix, play it on 10 different systems, see if you can figure the 'global average' of what's wrong with it.
Mix again.
Rinse, repeat until happy on at least 8 of the 10 systems.

Listen to similar-styled tracks you know sound good everywhere & see if you can identify what they are doing that's different to what you're doing.